# Jquery ui accordion defaulting to first active but not expanding

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

When the page loads, the arrow for the first section is pointing down indicating it is active.  However, the div doesn't show until I click a different section and click back to the first.  Other than this, the accordion is functioning properly.

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    $("#accordion").show();
});

<div id="accordion" style="display:none;">
<h3>div 1</h3>
<div id="div1">
    <input type="button" id="buttonId" />
</div>         

<h3>div 2</h3>
<div id="div2">

</div>

<h3>div 3</h3>
<div id="div3">

</div>
```

Comment: Please post some code of what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the display to none and showing via $("#accordion").show(); was causing it.